# XSLT - Transform XML input into HTML table with two columns

Tags: c#, xslt, xpath

Here is my source XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <employees>
    <region>
      <country>AUS</country>
      <count>3</count>
    </region>
    <region>
      <country>BEL</country>
      <count>1</count>
    </region>
    <region>
      <country>PER</country>
      <count>1</count>
    </region>
    <region>
      <country>ALA</country>
      <count>5</count>
    </region>
  </employees>
</root>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:variable name="map">
  <entry key="AGO">Angola</entry>
  <entry key="ALA">Alaska</entry>
  <entry key="AUS">Australia</entry>
  <entry key="PER">Peru</entry>
  <entry key="NKO">Not Known</entry>
  </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="employees">
    <html>
        <body>
        <div>
          <table>
            <xsl:variable name="test" select="region[count &gt; 0]"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="$test[position() mod 2 = 1]">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:variable name="countryLeft" select="country"></xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($map)/entry[@key=$countryLeft]"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:variable name="countryRight" select="following-sibling::region/country"></xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($map)/entry[@key=$countryRight]"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </div>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT should take every two regions from the XML and display them in a table row with two columns, one for each region. It should also map the source country code to the corresponding display name. In this example I'm storing the country map in an XSLT variable named `map`, but I could just as well read it from another XML file (using `document()` function) and the same issue occurs.

I'm expecting the output to be as follows:

```
Australia | Belgium
--------------------
Peru      |  Alaska
```

But it's returning:

```
Australia | Alaska
------------------
Peru      |  Alaska
```

Here is an XSLT fiddle demonstrating the issue:

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaGp/6

I suspect the issue is with mapping the country code to the display name, because if I don't do this then the country codes display correctly in the output HTML table.

I don't have much experience with XSLT so would appreciate some guidance as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Why is this tagged XSLT 2.0? Your stylesheet has `version="1.0"` and you seem to be using a Microsoft processor.

Comment: Sorry - I've removed this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I don't have a good explanation for this, but if you change:

```
<xsl:variable name="countryRight" select="following-sibling::region/country"></xsl:variable>
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="countryRight" select="following-sibling::region[1]/country"></xsl:variable>
```

it will work as expected: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaGp/7

Comment: The explanation is that without the `[1]`, `$countryRight` is a set of nodes containing all following siblings of the region, and the "=" comparison therefore returns all the entry keys that match any of these. In XSLT 1.0 `<xsl:value-of>` selects the first of these matching `entry` elements, which given your data would be ALA = Alland Islands. No idea where Alaska comes from, though!